# Webpack numbered chunks not loading correctly per config

Tags: javascript, config, webpack

So I have two different webpack configs I'm passing in an array that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        entry: entrypointsIE,
        output: outputIE,
        module: {
            loaders: [
                  // set of loaders that has one difference to load SCSS variables from a different location
            ]
        },
        resolveLoader: resolveLoader,
        resolve: resolve,
        plugins: plugins,
        devServer: devServer
    },
    {
        entry: entrypoints,
        output: output,
        module: {
            loaders: [
                 // loaders all the same as the IE9 except one difference in sass loader    
            ]
        },
        resolveLoader: resolveLoader,
        resolve: resolve,
        plugins: plugins,
        devServer: devServer
    }
]



output = {
    path: '/web/dist',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js'
};

outputIE = {
    path: '/web/dist',
    filename: '[name].ie.bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].ie.bundle.js'
};
```

and

```
apps.forEach(function(appName, index) {
    entrypoints[appName] = [ 'webpack/hot/dev-server', appName + '/app' ];
});

appsIE = apps;

appsIE.forEach(function(appName, index) {
    entrypointsIE[appName] = [ 'webpack/hot/dev-server', appName + '/app.ie' ];
});
```

The entrypoints are the exact same files (and this is where I think my problem is coming from). I have a conditional in my index.html which loads `framework.ie.js` if it detects IE, and `framework.js` if it does not. This works as expected. The problem is that it does not load the numbered chunks consistently. Sometimes I see `0.bundle.js` getting loaded, and sometimes I see `0.bundle.ie.js` getting loaded (regardless of whether `framework.ie.js` or `framework.js` got loaded).

Is there some way to make it consistently load the correct chunk or is there a way to just make sure that everything I need just gets loaded into the framework bundles without any chunks getting loaded by webpack?

Comment: Do you  have access to the headers of the page?

Comment: Yep I have access to the headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. Adding:

```
new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({maxChunks: 1}
```

Made it so my entrypoint chunks were the only ones created and so the logic works correctly.

Comment: Just saved the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using conditional comments to load the proper scripts based on browser vendor?

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="framework.ie.js"/>
    <script src="0.bundle.ie.js"/>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <script src="framework.js"/>
    <script src="0.bundle.js"/>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: The problem is that webpack is loading the numbered chunks via JSONP by itself.  So it will try and load whatever it wants anyway.